# How to bind checkboxes to Google Maps markers using knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

I'm creating an app that renders a Google Map of a city, with location markers for nearby locations. I'm rendering these locations by requesting locations within an 800-unit radius to the `google.maps.places.PlacesService` API. In addition, I have a number of checkboxes representing the place types (e.g. park, museum, etc.). When these boxes are checked or unchecked, I'd like for the map to dynamically update and show or hide the corresponding map markers. I'm using the knockout.js framework to help with the implementation.

My checkboxes are knockout observables, and I've managed to create an array of the checkboxes that changes dynamically within the html. However, even though the array changes, the map itself does not, even though I have set the types variable to be my location that stores the results from the checkbox selection (data.Locations.arrLocations). How do I go about getting the correct bindings in this case?

I've included my index.html and app.js files below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->
<div id='searchBar'>
    <p>Search: <strong data-bind="text: location"></strong></p>
    <p><input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: Locations' value='gym'> Gyms </p>
    <p> <input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: Locations' value='park'>Parks </p>
    <p> <input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: Locations' value='store'> Stores </p>
    <p> <input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: Locations' value='museum'> Museums </p>
    <p> <input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: Locations' value='zoo'> Zoos </p>

    <p>Search: <input data-bind="value: location" /></p>
    <div data-bind='text: ko.toJSON($data.Locations)'></div>


</div>


<div id='map'></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>


<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var data = {
    'Locations' : {
        'arrLocations': ['park', 'gym']
    }
};


function AppViewModel() {
    this.location = ko.observable("Barcelona, Spain");
    this.Locations = ko.observableArray(data.Locations.arrLocations);





}


var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var barcelona = {lat: 41.383, lng: 2.183};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: barcelona,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: barcelona,
    radius: 800,
    types: data.Locations.arrLocations,
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}


// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `subscribe` to changes in `Locations` and adjust your markers accordingly. To clear unwanted markers, you need to keep track of what markers you have added. I did this with a `markers` array. Each time `Locations` changes, all markers are removed, and then the search runs and adds markers.

```
viewModel.Locations.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    console.debug("Changing", newValue);
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; ++i) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
    service.nearbySearch({
        location: barcelona,
        radius: 800,
        types: newValue
    }, callback);
});
viewModel.Locations.notifySubscribers();
```

The `notifySubscribers` call causes the subscription to fire for the first run.

http://jsfiddle.net/53qfm5bz/1/